# How can I control the exact transform value of bezier curve handles?

Tags: bezier-curves, transforms

I want to make a perfect 90 degree bezier curve. How can I enter a value for the transform of the curve handles and control points?

Comment: You can enter numerical values for a selected control or handle using the sidebar.  If your curve tangents are aligned to an object's local axes, you would use the same X for a control and all its handles, and the same Y for the other control and all its handles, to create a 90 degree curve.  For an object not so aligned, you could create it while aligned and then rotate it, or you could use trigonometry to calculate exact-ish (limited to floating point precision) positions.

Comment: That answered my question, thanks.